# How often does a mega mystery box give 1 million coins?

Tags: subway-surfers

What is the probability of getting 1 million coins from a mega mystery box in Subway Surfers?

Comment: Hey there, I edited the tags on your post. Generally you should always include the game as a tag and only add in the platform of the game if it is available across multiple platforms and there are differences between the game on them. Welcome to arQAde and I hope you find your answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The chances of you getting a mega mystery box in Subway Surfers is about 1 thousandth of a percent (or .001%). However if you manage to earn 5 mystery boxes in a run the chance of getting a MMB is .01%.

Getting cash from the box is one out of ten. This means a cash MMB is .0001% and getting it out of a five box run is .001%.

Comment: The question isn't about how often you get the box, it's about how often a box gives 1M coins.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I fixed it.

Comment: Are you sure about *5 mystery boxes in **a run***? I am playing this game for last 2 years and often scored 5M+ but have never got two mystery boxes in *a single run*. Am I missing anything?

Comment: @hims056: No, you're not missing anything - this answer is flat-out wrong. You only get a single mystery box in a given run, no matter how far you go. The only exception to this rule is during super mystery box event days, where you can find multiple super mystery boxes.

Comment: @Gigazelle - Yeah and today is that special event of Super Mystery box. :)